# Attempted to load class "MyApp" from namespace

Tags: php, symfony, session, websocket, memcached

I using symfony 2 and ratchet and memcache on a websocket chat project ratchet working good with symfony and i tested it on the "hello world" app on the offical web site docs
but the problem is when I run this line

```
    new Chat(new MyApp(), $this->getContainer()),
```

i get this error

```
Attempted to load class "MyApp" from namespace
```

my command line code

```
<?php
// myapplication/src/sandboxBundle/Command/SocketCommand.php
// Change the namespace according to your bundle
namespace check\roomsBundle\Command;
use Ratchet\Session\SessionProvider;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler;
use Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcacheCache;
use Ratchet\App;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\MemcacheSessionHandler;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage;
// Include ratchet libs
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
// Change the namespace according to your bundle
use check\roomsBundle\Sockets\Chat;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class WsServerCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('sockets:start-chat')
            // the short description shown while running "php bin/console list"
            ->setHelp("Starts the chat socket demo")
            // the full command description shown when running the command with
            ->setDescription('Starts the chat socket demo')
        ;    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $output->writeln([
            'Chat socket',// A line
            '============',// Another line
            'Starting chat, open your browser.',// Empty line
        ]);
        $memcache = new \Memcache;
        $memcache->connect('localhost', 11211);

        $session = new SessionProvider(
            new Chat(new MyApp(), $this->getContainer()),
            new Handler\MemcacheSessionHandler($memcache)
        );

        $server = new App('localhost');
        $server->route('/sessDemo', $session);
        $server->run();
    }
}
```

the Chat.php code

```
<?php
namespace check\roomsBundle\Sockets;
use tuto\testBundle\Entity\Users;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServerInterface;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface as Container;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;



/**
 * This component will allow access to user data (FOSUserBundle)
 * for each connection in your Ratchet application.
 */
class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface, WsServerInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface
     */
    protected $_app;
    /**
     * @var \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface
     */
    protected $_container;
    /**
     * @param MessageComponentInterface $app
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     */
    public function __construct(MessageComponentInterface $app, ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->_app = $app;
        $this->_container = $container;
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        if (!isset ($conn->Session) || !$conn->Session instanceof Session) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Session is not defined. Make sure that SessionProvider is executed before FOSUserProvider.');
        }
        try {
            $token      = unserialize($conn->Session->get('_security_main'));
            $user       = $token->getUser();
            $provider   = $this->_container->get('fos_user.user_provider.username');
            $conn->User = $provider->refreshUser($user);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            $conn->User = null;
        }
        return $this->_app->onOpen($conn);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any use MyApp; on the top of your page. 
use AppBundle\Classes ?